# What type of plane/model is this twin-engine plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I would like to know what type/model is this plane, because I like it a lot.

[image: unknown aircraft]

Answer (score 9):

That’s a photo out of Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 of their default Beechcraft King Air 350i.

This version of the King Air is no longer produced by Textron Aviation, but it’s very similar to the current production iteration, the [King Air 360/360ER](https://beechcraft.txtav.com/en/king-air-360#Avionics).

[image]